# Why iota_view allows different integer template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have the following broken code, from what I can tell problem here is that `iota(0, n)`
returns me a `iota_view<int,int64>` and then obviously int can never be int64 that is greater than `INT_MAX`.
Easy fix is to just use `iota(0LL, n)`, but that seems error prone.

```
int main() {
  const int64_t n = 16LL*1024*1024*1024;
  auto ints = std::ranges::views::iota(0, n) |
              std::views::transform([](int64_t x) { return x * 10; });
  for (int64_t lookup : {49LL, 50LL, 51LL}) {
    const auto it = std::ranges::lower_bound(ints, lookup);
    if (it != ints.end()) {
      std::cout << *it << std::endl;
      std::cout << *it.base() << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

My best guess is that `iota_view` wants to work with "weird" second type, like some kind of +INF type, so that is why it needs 2 types, and nobody thought of forcing the first argument to match the second one if they are both ints.

Comment: FWIW, std::iota also has the same interface.  One potential use case you be if you want a sequence that when from `0` to `(2^integer_width_in_bits) - 1` and then roll back over to 0 if you need more than `(2^integer_width_in_bits) - 1` elements.

Comment: custom type with sentinel?

Comment: `std::weakly_incrementable` does not have to be an integer, [it can also be any iterator type](https://godbolt.org/z/EzPceYYqh), in that case, the second template parameter can be a different sentinel type.

Comment: @康桓瑋 But couldnt the iota_view concept/requires equivalent of (if first type is integer then second type must be same integer)